# How can I flip cards in a sequence at intervals?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building some flip cards using HTML and CSS. I got the part that if I hover over, the cards will flip themselves. Right now, I am trying to achieve that the card would automatically flip one after the other at a certain delay interval without hovering.
Each of flip card codes look like this, I have 4 of these cards in total:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("flip-card").style = " transform: rotateY(180deg); -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg); ";
}, 2000)
```

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: rgba(249, 207, 0, 0.1);
  color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card" style="cursor:pointer">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img
        src="xxx"
        class="images" alt=" " style="width:150px;height:150px;">
      <br>
      <h3>Realtime</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <p><br>Instant matching, voice <br> &amp; text live chat<br></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I achieve automatic card flipping with a delay? In another word, after 2s, card one will flip without any action, then after another 2s, card one will flip back, and card two will flip, and so on.

I tried the following JS codes, and it does not work:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("flip-card").style = " transform: rotateY(180deg); -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg); ";
    }, 2000)
```

Comment: What have you tried to create a sequence? Everything you're showing acts on all cards at once. You'll need some way to differentiate the cards, by class or index, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.flip-card');

/*
 * function to flip the card forward (rotateY 180deg) or back (no rotation)
 */
const flipCard = (card, direction) => {
  switch (direction) {
    case 'forward':
      card.children[0].classList.add("rotated");
      break;
    case 'back':
      card.children[0].classList.remove("rotated");
      break;
    default:
      card.children[0].classList.toggle("rotated");
  }
};

/*
 * function to check whether the automatic flip should skip the card
 */
const skipFlip = (cardIndex) => {
  return cards[cardIndex].getAttribute('data-isHovered') || false;
}

cards.forEach((card, index) => {
  card.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
    /*
     * onMouseEnter:
     *   1. flip the card forward (comment the function call if you do not want a "flip on mouse over" behaviour)
     *   2. add an attribute to prevent automatic flip
     */
    flipCard(card, 'forward');
    card.setAttribute('data-isHovered', true);
  });
  card.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
    /*
     * onMouseLeave
     *   1. flip the card back (comment the function call if you do not want a "flip on mouse over" behaviour)
     *   2. remove the attribute preventing the automatic flip
     */
    flipCard(card, 'back');
    card.removeAttribute('data-isHovered', false);
  });
});

/*
 * Automatically flip forward/back the cards one after the other, every 2 seconds
 * unless a card is hovered by the mouse (in which case the card will
 * stay in the same flipping position until the mouse moves out of it)
 */
let currCardIndex = 0;
window.setInterval(() => {
  const prevCardIndex = (currCardIndex === 0 && cards.length - 1) || currCardIndex - 1;

  if (!skipFlip(prevCardIndex)) {
    flipCard(cards[prevCardIndex], 'back');
  }
  if (!skipFlip(currCardIndex)) {
    flipCard(cards[currCardIndex], 'forward');
  }

  currCardIndex = currCardIndex === cards.length - 1 ? 0 : currCardIndex + 1;
}, 2000);
```

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card .rotated {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: rgba(249, 207, 0, 0.1);
  color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card" style="cursor:pointer">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="xxx" class="images" alt=" " style="width:150px;height:150px;">
      <br>
      <h3>Realtime 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <p><br>Instant matching, voice <br> &amp; text live chat<br></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flip-card" style="cursor:pointer">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="xxx" class="images" alt=" " style="width:150px;height:150px;">
      <br>
      <h3>Realtime 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <p><br>Instant matching, voice <br> &amp; text live chat<br></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flip-card" style="cursor:pointer">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="xxx" class="images" alt=" " style="width:150px;height:150px;">
      <br>
      <h3>Realtime 3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <p><br>Instant matching, voice <br> &amp; text live chat<br></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flip-card" style="cursor:pointer">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="xxx" class="images" alt=" " style="width:150px;height:150px;">
      <br>
      <h3>Realtime 4</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <p><br>Instant matching, voice <br> &amp; text live chat<br></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your welcome, @gshow8shac. Anyway, I just realized the code I wrote might need improvement, in case you want to keep the mouse over animation. In fact, when the page load, if you have your mouse on one of the cards it will trigger the flip and, if you do not move the mouse out before the card is flipped automatically, the card will flip "back", which I assume is not what you want. So, if you want the cards to flip both automatically and "onMouseOver", the code will require some tuning (using `classList.add("rotated")` and `classList.remove("rotated")` instead of `classList.toggle("rotated")`)

Comment: Ok, appreciate that. I will take a look. Also, when I get to the 4th card, I would like the flipping to start over on the first card. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @gshow8shac, if you want the card to keep flipping indefinitely, you need to use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()` and you have to change a little bit the code. I am going to update my answer to include these requirements

Comment: it worked like a charm. Thank you very much. Your solution is spot-on!!